# How can I fetch LDAP phone number?

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

The code below gets me the ldap username and full name...I am a little new to LDAP so I was wondering how may I also get the user phone number?

What is it that I need to add to my code to make it echo out the phone number as well?

```
<?php

$x=1;
if($x==1)
{
    //LDAP stuff here.
    $username = "stuff";
    $password = "stuffhere";

    echo("Authenticating...");
    $ds = ldap_connect('ldap host');

        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    //Can't connect to LDAP.
    if( !ds )
    {
        echo "Error in contacting the LDAP server -- contact ";
        echo "technical services!  (Debug 1)";

        exit;
    }

    //Connection made -- bind anonymously and get dn for username.
    $bind = @ldap_bind($ds);

    //Check to make sure we're bound.
    if( !bind )
    {
        echo "Anonymous bind to LDAP FAILED.  Contact Tech Services! (Debug 2)";

        exit;
    }

    $search = ldap_search($ds, "rdn here", "uid=$username");

    //Make sure only ONE result was returned -- if not, they might've thrown a * into the username.  Bad user!
    if( ldap_count_entries($ds,$search) != 1 )
    {
        echo "Error processing username -- please try to login again. (Debug 3)";
        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }

    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);

    //Now, try to rebind with their full dn and password.
    $bind = @ldap_bind($ds, $info[0][dn], $password);
    if( !$bind || !isset($bind))
    {
        echo "Login failed -- please try again. (Debug 4)";
        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }

    //Now verify the previous search using their credentials.
    $search = ldap_search($ds, "rdn here", "uid=$username");

    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
    if( $username == $info[0][uid][0] )
    {
echo $username;
     echo $info[0][cn][0]; 


        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error. Access Denied";
        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }
    ldap_close($ds);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: You should be able to see it in the returned information. Where you print out username add this: echo "<pre>".print_r($info[0],true)."</pre><br />";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519) gives `telephoneNumber` as the attribute for a phone number in the standard user schema. List this attribute in the requested attributes list in the search request. For more information about query a directory server, see ["LDAP: Using ldapsearch"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/) and ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/).